# Как выполнить рассылку сообщений VK более чем на 100 человек?

Tags: javascript, node.js, вконтакте

> По документации VK https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.send user_ids может быть не более 100

> Также существует метод https://dev.vk.com/method/execute который позволяет запускать несколько методов, в одном запросе.

Мне необходимо сделать рассылку пользователям с использованием execute, рассылка по отдельности не подойдет (1 метод - 1 юзер)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, можно отправлять несколько запросов. 2 запроса по 100 user_ids это уже 200 пользователей и т.д. Не забывайте про задержки, а то быстро в баню от вк уйдете)
В самом execute можно ппросто выполнить, если не ошибаюсь, до 30 запросов. То есть вместо 30 обращений к вк с messages.send вы делаете 1 обращение к execute, в котором уже идет 30 обращений к messages.send

Вот пример execute в котором вызывается два методы без параметров.

```
return [API.friends.get(), API.status.get()];
```

Вам туда нужно вставить свои методы, свои параметры. Лучше цикл использовать. Возможно еще какие-то операции придется, более подробно про execute написано в документации по вк апи.

Comment: Это все понятно, у меня возникла сложность в создании кода, для создания списка людей, чтобы отправлять методом сообщение по 100 человек. Их 1055, как мне написать код, чтобы рассылка прошла корректно, каждому человеку

Comment: разбить на массивы по 100 id, например, и потом для них вызвать. Что именно и где не получилось?

Comment: Решил вопрос, спасибо!